# I am working in the nycflights13 set in R

Tags: r

Can someone help? I keep getting an error numeric(0) instead of the answer of 99.45. :(

```
depdelay_upper <- quantile(flights$dep_delay, .997, na.rm = TRUE) 
depdelay_lower <- quantile(flights$dep_delay, .003, na.rm = TRUE) 
dep_out <- which(flights$dep_delay > depdelay_upper | flights$dep_delay < depdelay_lower)
Q1 <- ((nrow(flights$dep_delay)-length(dep_out))/nrow(flights$dep_delay)*100)
Q1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to take `nrow` of a vector. Either take the `length` of the vector or `nrow` of a dataframe.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

depdelay_upper <- quantile(flights$dep_delay, .997, na.rm = TRUE)
depdelay_lower <- quantile(flights$dep_delay, .003, na.rm = TRUE)
dep_out <- which(flights$dep_delay > depdelay_upper | flights$dep_delay < depdelay_lower)
Q1 <- ((nrow(flights)-length(dep_out))/nrow(flights)*100)
Q1

#[1] 99.45305
```

A good way to approach these errors is to run every step and substep individually. Running `nrow(flights$dep_delay)` on its own yields `NULL`, so you know that the issue lies there. Let me know if this works!